# How to insert a string at repeated intervals of another string in R

Tags: r, string, vector, rep

I have a vector of x elements in R. I would like to repeat this vector, inserting in another string every y repetitions. For example, I have the `sequence` below and want to generate `sequence_breaks`, which has a string of length 4 and repeats while inserting another string every 4th item. How can I make sequence_breaks, up to a certain length (say, 100)?

```
sequence <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
sequence_breaks <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'break', 
                     'd', 'a', 'b', 'break',
                     'c', 'd', 'a', 'break',
                     'b', 'c', 'd',' break')
```

Comment: Maybe `c(rbind(matrix(sequence, 3, 4), "break"))`

Comment: I think the complete answer would be `rep(c(rbind(matrix(sequence, 3, 4), "break")), length.out = 100)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one vectorised base R way :

```
insert_text <- 'break'
n <- 100
insert_num <- 4

#Extend sequence till length n
new_vec <- rep(sequence, length.out = n)
#Create a sequence over new_vec
inds <- seq_along(new_vec)
#index to insert new text
b <- inds %% insert_num == 0
#Shift values by 1
new_vec1 <- new_vec[inds - cumsum(b)]
#insert the value at b
new_vec1[b] <- insert_text

#  [1] "a"     "b"     "c"     "break" "d"     "a"     "b"     "break"
#  [9] "c"     "d"     "a"     "break" "b"     "c"     "d"     "break"
# [17] "a"     "b"     "c"     "break" "d"     "a"     "b"     "break"
# [25] "c"     "d"     "a"     "break" "b"     "c"     "d"     "break"
# [33] "a"     "b"     "c"     "break" "d"     "a"     "b"     "break"
# [41] "c"     "d"     "a"     "break" "b"     "c"     "d"     "break"
# [49] "a"     "b"     "c"     "break" "d"     "a"     "b"     "break"
# [57] "c"     "d"     "a"     "break" "b"     "c"     "d"     "break"
# [65] "a"     "b"     "c"     "break" "d"     "a"     "b"     "break"
# [73] "c"     "d"     "a"     "break" "b"     "c"     "d"     "break"
# [81] "a"     "b"     "c"     "break" "d"     "a"     "b"     "break"
# [89] "c"     "d"     "a"     "break" "b"     "c"     "d"     "break"
# [97] "a"     "b"     "c"     "break"
```

Comment: What is the `inds` object?

Comment: I forgot to copy it while pasting the answer. Check updated answer.